# Determine which of the following subset of $\mathbb{Q}[x] $ are ideal?

Tags: linear-algebra

This  Question is taken from Hoffman-Kunz books  page No : $138$  2nd edition Pearson publisher

Determine  which of the following  subset of  $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ are ideal  . When the set is  an ideal , find  its monic generator

$a)$ all even degree

$b)$ all $f$ such that  $f(2) = f(4) =0$

My attempt :  for option $a)$ If i take $f(x) = x^2 - 4x + 3$ that is even degree ,Then  $f$ will be  monic polynomial that generate the ideal $f \mathbb{Q}[x]$ as such  $f$ is the gcd  for all polynomial  $g$ such that   $g(x) = 0$

Im confused about option $b)$  i was  thinking about $f(x) = (x-2)(x-4)$

Any hints/solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) is not an ideal since if $f=x^2+x$ and $g=x^2$ then $f-g=x$ that has odd degree.

b) It is an ideal and it's the set $$\{f(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]\mid f(x)=(x-2)(x-4)g(x)\}=((x-2)(x-4))=...$$

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not an ideal because if you multiply by any odd degree polynomial you don't get an even degree polynomial,  as one way to see it.

The second is an ideal, generated by $(x-2)(x-4)$, since $f(2)=f(4)=0\implies (x-2)(x-4)\mid f(x)$.

Answer (score -2):

In the first case, $f(x)=x^2$ is a monic generator.

In the second case, you are right, $f(x)=(x-2)(x-4)$.

Comment: the first one is not an ideal. It's not stable for the addition.

Comment: ... or multiplication by $x$.